# Is Kinect Star Wars Region Free?

Tags: region-lock, kinect-star-wars

I want to know if Kinect Star Wars PAL is playable on a NTSC-US Xbox 360.

Thanks

Comment: I know the danish version has danish voice over, it is horrible!

Comment: you cant play PAL games on NTSC.

Comment: @iMAGEbox completely incorrect.

Comment: @kotekzot why? you cant play PAL games on NTSC region xbox.

Comment: @iMAGEbox because what you are saying is wrong. Whether a game from region X plays on a console in region Y is an arbitrary decision made by the publisher of each individual game.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Play Asia](http://www.play-asia.com/kinect-star-wars-paOS-13-49-en-70-4jra.html) the PAL Kinect Star Wars is region locked, so a PAL disk should not work on an NTSC-US Xbox 360, sorry!

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's true, I made the mistake of buying the game before making sure that I can play it...
The only difference is that my console is a NTSC-J console.
But just to emphasize what kotekzot said, I also have many games I bought here in Europe that I could play on my Xbox 360, so it really depends on each game.